# handling a compute intensive operation

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a web based application (large cargo aircraft weight and balance) in which the user enters pallet weights. When an individual pallet weight is entered, a number of checks have to be made to determine if that weight can be accepted. The checks are all relatively trivial in terms of compute cycles required; one is not. As I understand it, JavaScript is single-threaded, which I take to mean that if the user starts to enter a weight in another pallet position, he's going to be locked out until the previous weight is fully processed.

I can't afford to have the user waiting every time he enters a weight (which they don't have to do at the moment as the app currently doesn't make that last check properly). Currently I'm thinking of not doing the final compute-intensive step until all weights are entered and the user signifies so by clicking on a button. However, this will deprive the user of immediate feedback as to which weight initially triggered the problem, a problem in which multiple weights may contribute, and which is going to be hard to sort out if they have to wait until the last.

My Google searches on the topic have been somewhat useful, but I'm asking here for possible ideas for an up-to-date solution to the dilemma. Any suggestions are most welcome. The context of the problem can be observed by going to http://terryliittschwager.com/WB/JWB.php and selecting an aircraft.

Comment: what calculation would require that much time?

Comment: @ninjagecko The calculation is checking to see if what is called the "combined linear loading" is being exceeded. The cargo section of a 747 extends approximately 2,165 inches from balance arm (b.a.) 200 to b.a. 2365. The monocoque (and other) limitations are expressed in the combined linear loading maximum, and that is variable depdning on the location by the inch. So, I'm looking at a 2,165 iteration loop upon each entry that has to do a number of things. One of the problems is that the computers in say, Harare, Zimbabwe, aren't the latest. They're slow, and I have to set up for that.

Comment: Do you really have to loop for every inch?  Is there any way you could do less computations or have some computations pre-computed?

Comment: @zortacon Well, I think either of those is possible to some degree. However, inch by inch is the most politically acceptable solution. There's a long history here. Suffice it to say that when I grouped those inches together that had the same limit, a very capable loadmaster proved that it would be possible to not recognize an overload in improbable but possible conditions. That has gotten everyone's attention, and an inch by inch solution would set evryone's mind to rest. I did consider a pallet position width, but until I get to inch by inch, I'm just reducing the probability of exceeding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it client side, I'd recommend looking into WebWorkers.  They run on a separate thread from the main (DOM) JS thread.  Not supported in all browsers (of course), but is currently supported in Chrome, FF, Safari, and IE 10.

EDIT: The MDN for [WebWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_web_workers) is a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. It has to be done client-side (which I should said) because it has to be able to run when Internet access is unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

you could use Ajax for the long one and javascript for the rest.  Or break up the computation if possible and do it a bit at a time.  http://www.sitepoint.com/multi-threading-javascript/

Comment: Thanks for the input. Unfortunately I neglected to say in my original question that this has to run without Internet access when necessary.

Comment: web server != internet access.  I have created several offline solutions that were powered by a perl using the Net::Server.  Or install apache or IIS.  In any case, the processing is done outside of javascript so there is no blocking.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought of that possibility. Live and learn. Thank you.